# Proving that free group actions are faithful.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, free-groups

Assume group $G$ acts on set $X$. My course notes say this:

> Free action is a special case of faithful action. To have faithful action it suffices that any $g \neq e$ in $G$ moves something (but not necessarily everything) in $X$ to a different location, whereas free action requires that any $g \neq e$ has no fixed point.

My understanding: faithful actions cannot have all fixed points for a non-identity function because essentially each function must be unique, and the identity function has all fixed points, and therefore no other function can have all fixed points. In a free action, no function other than the identity function can have *any* fixed points.

**Why can't there be two distinct functions, neither having any fixed points, which are equal on all points of $X$?** Is that obviously impossible on its face?

My attempt to show why that's impossible: assume we have a free action of $G$ on $X$. Assume it's not faithful, so we have $g_1 \neq g_2 \in G$ such that for all $x \in X$, we have $g_1(x) = g_2(x)$.

If one of $g_1, g_2$ were the identity function, then we'd have $g_1(x) = g_2(x) = x$ for all $x \in X$, which by the definition of a free action would imply that both $g_1, g_2$ are the identity function, which violates our premise, so we can assume that neither is the identity function.

We have $g_2^{-1}(g_1(x)) = g_2^{-1}(g_2(x)) = g_2^{-1}g_2(x) = e(x) = x$, so $g_2^{-1} \neq e$ has a fixed point at $g_1(x)$, which contradicts the assumed free action. Therefore the free action must be faithful.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand the context of your question. Are you assuming that the action is free, or perhaps faithful? If the action is not faithful, then of course you could have two such functions. But if $f$ and $g$ were two such, then $fg^{-1}$ would fix all points of $X$, and so the action would be neither free not faithful.

Comment: Functions are defined by their actions on points. If two functions have the same value for all points, they are not *distinct*.

Comment: @DerekHolt I was assuming that the action is free but not faithful, and trying to find a contradiction. Maybe I should have just done what you did, and assumed $f$ and $g$ were two distinct functions with no fixed points that are equal on all points of $X$, and then as you say, some composition of one with the inverse of the other would have all fixed points, and can't be the identity (I think), which would violate the assumption of free action.

Comment: Incidentally, it is strange and a little confusing to refer to elements of an abstract group $G$ as functions. It is better to call them group elements. The action of $G$ on $X$ corresponds to a homomorphism $\phi:G \to {\rm Sym}(X)$ and then the elements $\phi(g)$ for $g \in G$ are (bijective) functions from $X$ to $X$, but the elements of $g$ are not functions per se.